# Count number of points outside of buffer

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, buffer

I'm trying to count the total points outside of a buffer zone using PostgreSQL. The intention is to find all of the schools that do not fall within a 2-mile radius of libraries.

I've either gotten results that return the total number of schools or nothing at all.

What is wrong with my query?

```sql
SELECT ST_Buffer(mdlibrary.geom, 3218, 'endcap = round join = round') AS librarybuffer, mdlibrary.anchorname AS libraryname, count(mdschool.*) AS totalschools
FROM mdlibrary, mdschool
WHERE mdschool.geom IS NULL
GROUP BY mdlibrary.geom, mdlibrary.anchorname
```

Answer (score 7):

Try to tackle you task in a bit different way. This question was already explained here [Postgis – Opposite of ST_Within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35977772/postgis-opposite-of-st-within).

Let's assume there are two layers `"schools"` (orange) and `"libraries"` (purple), see image below.

[image: input]

So, your query can look like

```sql
SELECT s.*
FROM schools AS s
WHERE s."osm_id" NOT IN (
    SELECT s."osm_id"
    FROM schools AS s, libraries AS l
    WHERE st_within(s.geometry, st_buffer(l.geometry, 20))
 )
```

Find the output below (pink circles), including the schools that do not fall within a radius to libraries.

[image: output]

To count those schools, simply use `COUNT()`

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "schools_outside"
FROM schools AS s
WHERE s."osm_id" NOT IN (
    SELECT s."osm_id"
    FROM schools AS s, libraries AS l
    WHERE st_within(s.geometry, st_buffer(l.geometry, 20))
)
```

Additionally you may try using slightly adjusted query

```sql
SELECT s.*
FROM schools AS s
WHERE s."osm_id" NOT IN (
    SELECT s."osm_id"
    FROM schools AS s, libraries AS l
    WHERE st_disjoint(s.geometry, st_buffer(l.geometry, 20)) IS FALSE
)
```

P.S. Mind the CRS (*SRID*) for your area.

Comment: But Beware! for it is written in the holy book of computational effectivity: *Never shallt thou create or use buffers on-the-fly for proximity searches!*, and furthermore: *Nor is there need for true containment checks, for it is either in proximity, or not!* - best use `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM libraries AS l WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, l.geom)` as it terminates the subquery once a truthy (`1`) tuple is identified. Powered by the index.

Comment: Thank you for info! Shall I use alias for Buffer instead of *on-the-fly*?

Comment: Don't use buffers at all. Note the usage of `ST_DWithin` in my comment (note also that I forgot the distance parameter in the function...).

Comment: Thank you. Can you adjust my answer? Or shall I delete it complete then you can write a correct one? Do not want to litter.

Comment: No! The most important part of it all is what you covered elegantly; tests for *non*-intersection are tricky, and can only be solved by checking against a set of actual intersections to avoid a cartesian product. Your queries will work just fine, but I suggest to dive into why and how indexes kick in, and check on the benefits of `[NOT] EXISTS` in many cases (search e.g. *"`NOT IN` vs `ǸOT EXISTS`"*)